# Rails 4 Blog /:year/:month/:title with clean routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, friendly-id

In Rails 4 is there another cleaner way to achieve routes, such as:

```
/blog/2014/8/blog-post-title
/blog/2014/8
/blog/2014
/blog/2014/8/tags/tag-1,tag-2/page/4
/blog/new OR /blog_posts/new
```

I've tried the following using `FriendlyId` (as well as `acts-as-taggable` for tag param and `kaminari` for page param):

**blog_post.rb**

```
 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :finders]

 def to_param
   "#{year}/#{month}/#{title.parameterize}"
 end

 def slug_candidates
 [
    :title,
    [:title, :month, :year]
 ]
 end

 def year
   created_at.localtime.year
 end

 def month
   created_at.localtime.month
 end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  match '/blog_posts/new', to: 'blog_posts#new', via: 'get'
  match '/blog_posts/:id/edit', to: 'blog_posts#edit', via: 'get'
  match '/blog_posts/:id/edit', to: 'blog_posts#update', via: 'post'
  match '/blog_posts/:id/delete', to: 'blog_posts#destroy', via: 'destroy'
  match '/blog(/page/:page)(/tags/:tags)(/:year)(/:month)', to: 'blog_posts#index', via: 'get'
  match '/blog/:year/:month/:title', to: 'blog_posts#show', via: 'get'
  resources 'blog', controller: :blog_posts, as: :blog_posts
```

Used resources so can have path and url helpers as normal.

This works (minus update yet), but feels very ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: you don't need the new, edit, update, destroy routes which are included in resources...

Comment: I need those so it is `/blog_posts/action` instead of `/blog/action`, otherwise it will interpret the action as a year parameter e.g. `year="new"`. Maybe there is another approach just in respect to those route definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Friendly_ID**

I think your major problem is that you're trying to keep your `/:year/:month/:tags` in a single set of params - you'd be much better suited to sending them separately, and building the resource as you need:

```
#config/routes.rb
scope "/blog" do
   resources :year, controller :blog_posts, only: :show, path: "" do
      resources :month, controller : blog_posts, only: :show, path: "" do
         resources :title, controller: blog_posts, only: :show, path: ""
      end
   end
end
resources :blog_posts, path: :blog -> domain.com/blog/new
```

This looks unruly, but will hopefully provide a structure of routing whereby you'll be able to send specific requests to your Rails app (`domain.com/blog/...`), and have them handled by the `blog_posts#show` action

Here's how I'd take care of that:

```
#app/controllers/blog_posts_controller.rb
Class BlogPostsController < ApplicationController

   def show
      case true
         when params[:year].present?
           @posts = Post.where "created_at >= ? and created_at < ?", params[:year]
         when params[:month].present?
           @posts = Post.where "created_at >= ? and created_at < ?", params[:month]
         when params[:id].present?
           @posts = Post.find params[:id]
      end
   end

end

#app/views/blog_posts/show.html.erb
<% if @posts %>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= link_to post.title, blog_post_path(post) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% if @post %>
   <%= link_to post.title, blog_post_path(post) %>
<% end %>
```

--

**Slugs**

To create the slugs, you'd then just be able to use the title for `friendly_id`:

```
#app/models/blog_post.rb
Class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

This might not work out of the box (in fact, it probably won't), but what I'm trying to demonstrate is that I think you'd be better splitting your handling of the params / `year` / `month` / `title` into your controller

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have used this with some tweaking (question updated). `/blog/new` works and `/blog/1/edit`. But the last parameters is always given as an id e.g. `/blog/2014` results in `id: 2014` and `/blog/2014/5/blah-blah` results in `year_id:2014, month_id:6, id: blah-blah`. Also, update patches to the full `/blog/2014/8/blah`, which there is no route for. I could manually use post in form?

Comment: Ah I think this can be fixed if you take the `resources :blog` ref and put it below the others - let me update for you!!

Comment: Mmm, I just tried this and still the same issues, with `/blog/new` and edit actions now not working, though.

Comment: haha okay. Can you share your `rake routes` in your question?

Comment: Added. (Thanks for continued support!)

Comment: No problem - let me take a look thanks. Just getting over the James Foley news

Comment: Yes, utterly shocking... Puts everything in perspective.

Comment: Okay thanks for your update! Did you change your routes to reflect the `resources :blog_posts` being at the bottom?

Comment: Oh, the original edit didn't use the rake routes after that change. I've added that version now.

Comment: Thanks buddy - let me check

Comment: Okay - how long have you got? Would you mind if I get some food, then we can go into chat about this?

Comment: Haha, of course not - you're answering my question! I've got time - a few hours!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59679/discussion-between-todomyname-and-rich-peck).